# Table-like means of storage in MIT App Inventor 2

Tags: app-inventor

I wanted to create an app in **App Inventor**, which asks for someone's name, and stores it, plays a game, stores the score alongside it like a table, and then you can compare scores.

Well, `TinyDB` is not something I am looking for. Any other method of (free) storage I can use for this available in App Inventor? `Fusion tables` looks good, is it free?

Comment: yes, you can use fusiontables and it's free, see the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty) how to use it

Comment: Thanks, you should have posted as an answer, I would have accepted it and got you some rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can use fusiontables and it's free, see the [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty) how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Tables are free. The  [Pizza Party tutorial](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/pizzaparty)  demonstrates use of Fusion Tables. Another option is http://webdb.satukarya.com/ which is a service for storing JSON objects via a Web API. It is also free, and the author offers AI2 code for reading/writing from App Inventor.